# Xamarin forms - Code is building successfully in Visual Studio 2017 (Release build) but not in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, prism

When i am building my code in Visual Studio 2017 (release build), the build is successful. However, when the i am trying to build the same code in Visual Studio 2019, i am receiving the following error :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2056,5):
>   Error XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method:
>   'System.Void
>   Prism.Unity.UnityContainerExtension::RegisterSingleton(System.Type,System.Type)'
>   in assembly: 'Prism.Unity.Forms.dll' --->
>   Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve
>   Unity.Registration.InjectionMember at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference
>   reference) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference
>   reference) at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference
>   reference) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkGenericArguments(IGenericInstance
>   instance) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.GetOriginalMethod(MethodReference method)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method) at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue() --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace --- at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue() at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue() at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process() at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context) at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context) at
>   Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step) at
>   Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context) at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger,
>   LinkContext& context) at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   res) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask() at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()

Need some help regarding this.

Comment: Have you tried to update the prism nuget package?

Comment: I am using prism version 7.1.0.431. Not able to upgrade to the latest stable version : 7.2.0.1422 as it is breaking some of the implemented functionalities.

Comment: Is you linking set to None?

Comment: Linking is set to : Sdk Assemblies Only

Comment: Would it build successfully if you change it to none?

Comment: Yes, I have checked. When the linking is set to : None, the build is successful. However, this would increase the apk size right?

Comment: Yes, it will increase the apk size.

Comment: In this case, I recommand you to use Custom Linker Configuration, this is very good tutorial :  https://progrunning.net/fixing-xamarin-forms-linker-issues/